# how to locate ::Before element in Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium

[image]

unable to click on this specific  "X" element

Comment: Have you added implicit wait?

Comment: what is the error you are getting. what code are you using. without that people can only speculate, could not help you.

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible

Comment: Put in a sleep before interacting with it to debug. If that works, then you need an **Explicit wait** to wait for the element to be visible. Please post some code of what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

try with following xpath, It may works.

```
//*[@id='ngdialog1']//*[@class='ngdialog-close']
```

In java

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ngdialog1']//*[@class='ngdialog-close']").click();
```

Answer (score 0):

try using following code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='ngdialog1']//table//following-sibling::div[1]").click();
```